# ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon + WSL2

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2

I sometime have an issue with Docker on my WSL2 installation (Windows 2004) :

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. 
Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

And of course I have unset `DOCKER_HOST`.

However Docker daemon is running on Windows:

```
$ tasklist.exe | grep docker
com.docker.service            7016 Services                   0     46'884 K
com.docker.backend.exe        9904 Console                    1     18'456 K
docker-mutagen.exe           15108 Console                    1      8'448 K
com.docker.proxy.exe         21368 Console                    1     17'960 K
```

And my Ubuntu distribution is running WSL:

```
$ wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2

$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
```

[image]

Its strange that Docker says I don't have any WSL 2 distro:

[image]

Comment: One of the prerequisites of installing the docker WSL 2 back-end is that you have installed the Linux kernel update package [according to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#prerequisites). Does that solve your issue?

Comment: @octagon_octopus I have the latest kernel. Usually my problem is solved when I reboot the PC.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned it only works sometimes indeed. It's a very strange issue then. I could only suggest reinstalling Docker Desktop maybe, although that does not answer what is going wrong.